# Vapor 2, Fluent model subclass

Tags: swift, vapor

I'm using Vapor 2 and trying to create non-final model to subclass it. Is it possible? I have following code for abstract model:

```
class MongoObject: Model, JSONRepresentable {

    let storage = Storage()

    let creationDate: Date

    init() {
        creationDate = Date()
    }

    required init(row: Row) throws {
        creationDate = try row.get(KeyPath.creationDate)
    }

    func makeRow() throws -> Row {
        var row = Row()
        try row.set(KeyPath.creationDate, creationDate)
        return row
    }

    func makeJSON() throws -> JSON {
        var json = JSON()
        try json.set(KeyPath.id, id)
        try json.set(KeyPath.creationDate, creationDate)
        return json
    }

}

extension MongoObject: Preparation {

    class func prepare(model: Creator) { }

    static func prepare(_ database: Database) throws {
        try database.create(self) { (builder) in
            builder.id()
            builder.date(KeyPath.creationDate)
            prepare(model: builder)
        }
    }

    static func revert(_ database: Database) throws {
        try database.delete(self)
    }

}
```

but got compilation error:

> method 'make(for:)' in non-final class 'MongoObject' must return
>   `Self` to conform to protocol 'Parameterizable'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your non-final "abstract" model with subclasses is conforming to `Parameterizable` as part of the `Model` conformance. Parameterizable requires returning `Self`. By default this is implemented by reading the entity's id from the path component. The problem you now get is that the compiler can't return `Self` for subclasses since it's implemented on a higher model.

The solution is pretty straightforward, you cannot do subclassing here.

Answer (score 0):

I might be too late, but I was having the exact same problem and all I had to do was make the class final.

> method 'make(for:)' in ***non-final class*** 'MongoObject' must return  Self to conform to protocol 'Parameterizable'